# Scraping images in nested divs

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the images from a personal imgur gallery: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHf6v.jpg so I can then format them and prepare them for linking to my website. I want a list of all the image links, but for some reason I can't get any. I also tried with a CSS selector but no luck. I suspect it might be because they are too deeply nested. Also I don't have much experience with scraping.

This is what I came up with using Python and BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Make a GET request to the website
r = requests.get("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHf6v.jpg")

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the element with tag "div" and class "PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded"
div = soup.find_all("div", class_="PostContent-imageWrapper-rounded")

if div:
    # Find all the "img" elements inside the div
    img_tags = div.find_all('img')

    # Print the src attribute of each img element
    for img in img_tags:
        print(img['src'])
else:
    print("Div not found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use their API:

```py
import requests

# FIR1BL1 is the album name
url = "https://api.imgur.com/post/v1/albums/FIR1BL1?client_id=546c25a59c58ad7&include=media"

data = requests.get(url).json()

for m in data['media']:
    print(m['url'])
```

Prints:

```
https://i.imgur.com/q4UuhEq.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/WFVRr9Q.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/QSl0OpM.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/0yKgw0Y.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/BV2JfUw.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/hITF8Y9.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/HxQDu52.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/S13WUFn.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/MDEN7G6.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/HNuWMOw.jpeg
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on how you generated this URL. Should I register an Application, set Postman and all that is written here: https://apidocs.imgur.com/
or there is another way?

Comment: @Donchev I think yes, registering the application is correct way to do it. I got the api URL from Web-developer Tools -> Network tab, but the `client_id=` could change without warning.

Comment: One last thing... I notice that when I view the links to the images manually from my profile the extensions are .jpg, but when I view them as someone else (not the author of the post) the links are exactly the same BUT the extensions are .jpeg
Any idea why?

Comment: @Donchev That depends on the server, how it handles the images. Try to do `print(data)`, there is more information about the images - I think even the original filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You are not finding them because they are not there, The images are loaded from the imgur api. to see the request is loading them:

1. Open a new tab
2. Open developer tools and go to network tab
3. open your imgur link in the tab (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHf6v.jpg is the one you have)
4. use the search to find this request `https://api.imgur.com/post/v1/albums/FIR1BL1` or something similar
5. This request has the data you looking for try to reconstruct something similar and use request.json() to parse it